# Moebius strip as a fibre bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I've alrealdy asked this question, but now I have more clear ideas, so I'm going to ask again and see if I'll understand a bit more. 
It's about the trivialisation of the Moebius strip as a bundle on $S^1$ with fibre an open interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$.

First of all, I write the strip as $E=[0,1]^2/\sim$, where $(0,y)\sim(1,1-y)$ and the other points of $[0,1]^2$ are equivalent to themselves.
Then I write $S^1=[0,1]/\sim$, where $0\sim 1$.
Now I define the projection $\pi: E\rightarrow S^1$, $\pi([(x,y)])=[x]$ (here with $[\cdot]$ I mean the equivalence class of $\cdot$). Now I want to find an open cover  $U_1,U_2$ of $S^1$ (two arcs of $S^1$ substantially) such that there exist homeomorphisms $\phi_i:\pi^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow U_i\times I$, $i=1,2$ and this homeomorphisms have the property that $\pi_1\circ \phi_i=\pi$, where $\pi_1$ is the canonical projection onto the first factor.

Now, my problem is write properly the homeomorphisms. Suppose that $S^1\ni[0]\notin U_1$, so $[0]\in U_2$. Then $\pi^{-1}(U_1)$ is exactly $U_1\times I$ and as homeomorphism I can choose the identity. But now my problem is $\pi^{-1}(U_2)$ which contains the gluing edges.
Can anyone help me, please?

For example if $S^1\supset U_2=([0,2/5)\cup(3/5,1])/\sim$, then I could define $\phi_2([(x,y)])=(x,y)$ if $0\le x<2/5$ and $\phi_2([(x,y)])=(x,1-y)$ if $3/5<x<1$. But now the problem is prove that $\phi_2$ is a homeomorphism, I'm confused.

Comment: Is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543058/trivialisation-of-moebius-strip) the previous question you are referring to? It is good to have that link handy, so people can understand the context better, and don't end up repeating what you already know.

Comment: Yes, that is the question.

Comment: You have the right idea. To prove that $\phi_2$ is a homeomorphism, you need to appeal to your quotient map.

Comment: @Neal: Do you mean that I have to show that the preimage of an open set in $U_1 \times I$ is an open set in E?